Regular Updates But Still On 22.04.2 Rather Than 22.04.4
I have a desktop and server which both run Ubuntu 22.04.
Problem is that my desktop - despite frequent update scripts - still remains at 22.04.2
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

even though my server seems to be running 22.04.4 from its installation ~ 2 months ago.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Why is this ?
EDIT
Server Sources List
  GNU nano 6.2                                  /etc/apt/sources.list *                                          
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

Desktop Sources List
/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse

/etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -la
total 216
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  5 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jul 10 14:23 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 15  2021 balena-etcher.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 15  2021 balena-etcher.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 blaze-ubuntu-rtbth-dkms-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  134 Oct 27  2022 blaze-ubuntu-rtbth-dkms-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 blaze-ubuntu-rtbth-dkms-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150 Jul  5 12:18 blaze-ubuntu-rtbth-dkms-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150 Feb 22  2023 blaze-ubuntu-rtbth-dkms-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 14  2021 brave-browser-release.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 14  2021 brave-browser-release.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 14  2021 brave.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 14  2021 brave.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 29  2022 colingille-ubuntu-freshlight-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 29  2022 colingille-ubuntu-freshlight-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Oct 27  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Jul  5 12:18 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Feb 22  2023 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Jul  5 12:18 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  110 Oct 27  2022 docker.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Feb 22  2023 docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Oct 27  2022 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Oct 27  2022 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  121 Feb 22  2023 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Jul  5 12:18 helkaluin-ubuntu-webp-pixbuf-loader-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Feb 22  2023 helkaluin-ubuntu-webp-pixbuf-loader-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  134 Oct 27  2022 kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  134 Jul  5 12:18 kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  134 Feb 22  2023 kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 linuxuprising-ubuntu-java-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 Oct 27  2022 linuxuprising-ubuntu-java-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 linuxuprising-ubuntu-java-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Oct 27  2022 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 Jul  5 12:18 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 Feb 22  2023 lyzardking-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-trunk-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-trunk-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Jul  5 12:18 microsoft-edge-beta.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Oct 27  2022 microsoft-edge-beta.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Feb 22  2023 microsoft-edge-beta.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 Oct 27  2022 mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Jul  5 12:18 mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Feb 22  2023 mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65 Jul  5 12:18 mono-official-vs.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201 Jul  5 12:18 mysql.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201 Oct 27  2022 mysql.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201 Feb 22  2023 mysql.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Jul  5 12:18 neo4j.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Oct 27  2022 neo4j.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Feb 22  2023 neo4j.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  2  2021 nodesource.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  2  2021 nodesource.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   99 Oct 27  2022 opera-stable.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   99 Oct 27  2022 opera-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 slyon-ubuntu-iwd_nm-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  126 Oct 27  2022 slyon-ubuntu-iwd_nm-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 27  2022 slyon-ubuntu-iwd_nm-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 22  2023 slyon-ubuntu-iwd_nm-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 22  2023 slyon-ubuntu-iwd_nm-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Jul  5 12:18 sublime-text.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Oct 27  2022 sublime-text.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Feb 22  2023 sublime-text.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 27  2022 swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 18  2023 swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  152 Jul  5 12:18 swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  152 Feb 22  2023 swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 thierry-f-ubuntu-fork-michael-gruz-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 25  2022 thierry-f-ubuntu-fork-michael-gruz-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  205 Jul  5 12:18 ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172 Oct 27  2022 ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  205 Feb 22  2023 ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  173 Mar 17  2021 vivaldi.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  121 Jul  5 12:18 vscode.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  203 Oct 27  2022 vscode.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  121 Feb 22  2023 vscode.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  243 Jul  5 12:18 warpdotdev.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  160 Jul  5 12:18 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list

Kernels
Desktop -
$ uname -a
Linux inspiron-5567 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Server -
$ uname -a 
Linux iushcxjoisajxc.xyz 5.15.0-113-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 10 08:16:17 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT 2
I did the suggested entry of
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main multiverse universe restricted

to my /etc/apt/sources.list and did an update.
457 packages were updated. But I remain on Ubuntu 22.04.2 albeit with a kernel that is newer.
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

~$ uname -a
Linux inspiron-5567 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I still don't know why my machine remains at 22.04.2 rather than 22.04.4  . . .
EDIT 3
Did additional entry to cover jammy-updates on mook765's advice.
227 more updates.
Ubuntu 22.04.4 at last.
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

~$ uname -a
Linux inspiron-5567 6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


As long as you have all the updates, it really does not matter

You mean that 22.04.x only refers to an initial installation ? If that's so, why did it change from 22.04.1 to 22.04.2 ?

Can you post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list for both the computers?

Can you post the kernels the two computers are using?

Added . . . . .

It looks like you are running a non standard kennel on your desktop. My desktop shows 5.15.0.113.113

A fully-updated jammy desktop (HWE) should be running kernel 6.5.0.42.42.1~22.04.1. Please edit your question to show the complete output of sudo apt update and of sudo apt upgrade

I don't see any UPDATES listed in your desktop sources; ie. it appears as if you don't want that machine to get updates; which I suggest you do need (ie. that appears to be your issue).   Did you paste the whole sources file for your desktop?? as only a single line (of source packages & not updated packages) was listed.

Mañana, amigos!

Changed sources.list file and updated. 457 packages updated. Got same old 22.04.2 but a newer kernel.

@Trunk You still didn't add jammy-updates to your sources.

@mook765  Got it !
